# Pick up new values to ActiveX Combobox, skip empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to pick up values to ActiveX combobox on Worksheet automatically depending on the range values. I would like to activate the code each time user opens drop down list. I came up with current solution but some times it shows values x 3 or 4. What is possibly wrong with the code?

In range B55:B71 I have list values. They are displayed by formula and some of them are `=if(A1="";"";A1)` (example formula to understand the result) (empty).

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommercialBox_Click()
Dim RngCom As Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.Clear
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database")
    For Each RngCom In .Range(.Range("B55"), .Range("B71" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If RngCom.Value <> vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.AddItem RngCom.Value
    Next RngCom
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just: `For Each RngCom In .Range("B55:B71")`. And don't you want to tie this code to `Private Sub CommercialBox_DropButtonClick()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

You state you want this code to run when user **opens** up the dropdown, and not when a value is **clicked**. Your current code would only run when a value is chosen. `DropButtonClick` will be activated when opening drop down list.

Also you stated a fixed range from `B55:B71` so why not implement that...

```
Private Sub CommercialBox_DropButtonClick()
Dim RngCom As Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.Clear
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact database")
    For Each RngCom In .Range("B55:B71")
        If RngCom.Value <> vbNullString Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").CommercialBox.AddItem RngCom.Value
    Next RngCom
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This almost works, the problem now is that when I pick up the value, nothing getting picked up.

Comment: @user7202022, You have to rework the `Click` event for that probably.